# How can I force the Sense UI home screen on my Evo to landscape?

Tags: htc-sense, home-screen, htc-evo

I have an Evo running with very default settings. How can I force the home screen (Which I believe to be running Sense UI if I'm not confused) to be in landscape format.  I use my kickstand all the time, and it's a pain to tilt my head to look at the home screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The factory implementation doesn't support landscape.  (When you configure the background, you get a hint about this from the dimensions of the image).

Lanscape mode [would require a custom ROM](http://androinica.com/2010/09/19/new-htc-sense-are-already-being-ported-to-other-htc-devices/).

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned Sense UI but you could use **LauncherPro** which has the ability to auto-rotate the homescreen. Personally I believe LauncherPro is a far better implemented launcher than Sense.

If you purchase **LauncherPro Plus** you'll get 90% of the Sense UI widgets anyway but also you'll get an increase in speed and stability.

[LauncherPro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/launcherpro/com.fede.launcher#):

[image: LauncherPro QR Code]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been using the last few weeks. I don't like it near as well as Sense, but it does rotate, which is the biggest deal to me of all.  I just don't understand why Sense on the Evo doesn't rotate automatically - like the Epic.